# Query from firebase database from specific date

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to query for data of a specific date the formatting of data is specified below.

```
[![][1]][1]
```

```
databaseReference = database.getReference("TopScoreUpdate");  
 databaseReference.orderByChild("date/date").equalTo(29).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Log.i("entityCheck", String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()));
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot1:dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {}
```

for the above code written I am not getting result it shows no result found. I have declared in ".Index" of Firebase rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> for the above code written I am not getting result it shows no result found.

This is happening because you are missing a child. To solve this, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference topScoreUpdateRef = rootRef.child("TopScoreUpdate");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            long date = ds.child("prful/date/date").getValue(Long.class);
            Log.d("TAG", "date: " + date);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
topScoreUpdateRef.orderByChild("prful/date/date").equalTo(29).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

See, the explicit call to `prful` should be added in your reference. The result in the logcat will be:

```
date: 29
```

Printed out as many times as it appears in your database.